# Problem with unidentical rows that I want to remove from the result in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a snapshot view that once a status of an order changes from 2 [completed] to 3 [cancelled], it doesnt replace the previous row but adds a new one with the new status, which makes the total price double than it should be [or more, depends on how many items were cancelled].
Is there an intelligent way to deal with it?

Comment: This question definitely needs more info about how your view was created. But it looks like its appending vs updating. So just look into how to write update statement in bq [https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#update_statement] and that should take care of not having new rows for each status update. Just a thought.

Comment: is there an active row flag that you can use to filter on or a common id along with inserted date?  You would need to example a small set of your data for someone to really be able to assist